# How to join four tables using Linq in asp.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, join

There is something wrong with my query. 
I can't manage to join my 4 tables. What am I doing wrong?

```
 var id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["id"]);
 var ShowCompetenties = from d in db.Docent
          join dc in db.DocentenCompetenties on d.DocentID equals dc.DocentID
          where dc.DocentID == id
          join c in db.Competenties on dc.CompetentiesID equals c.CompetentiesID
          join dl in db.DocentenLocaties on d.DocentID equals dl.DocentID
          where dl.DocentID == id
          join l in db.Locaties on dl.LocatieID equals l.LocatieID
          select new ShowCompetenties { Docenten = d, Competenties = c, DocentenCompetenties = dc, Locaties = l, DocentenLocaties = dl};
```

I have two  junction tables = DocentenLocaties and DocentenCompetenties

.cshtml

```
<h4>My Locations</h4>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
  @item.Locaties.Name @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteLocaties", new { id = item.DocentenLocaties.DocentenLocatieID })
}

<h4>My Competences</h4>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
  @item.Competenties.Name @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteCompetenties", new { id = item.DocentenCompetenties.DocentenCompetentiesID })
}
```

Comment: Code looks sane at the first glance, although this mix of join-where-join-where is a bit weird. Anyway, do you see any errors? Or how doesn't this work for you?

Comment: Well it either loops only "Docenten" or "Competences" and not the two togheter.

Comment: Assuming you are talking about view part. This code does not look right indeed. If `Model` is the `ShowCompetencies` that the query produces, then `@item.Competenties` is a colleciton, you cannot just call `Name` on it. Likewise with the rest

Comment: What is the alternative then? Btw when I delete join dl in db.DocentenLocaties on d.DocentID equals dl.DocentID
          where dl.DocentID == id
          join l in db.Locaties on dl.LocatieID equals l.LocatieID my foreach for "Docenten" works

Comment: Why don't you have navigation properties set up?

Answer (score 2):

Set up your navigation properties, then:

```
var id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["id"]);
var ShowCompetenties = db.Docent
  .Include(d=>d.Competenties)
  .Include(d=>d.Locaties)
  .First(d=>d.DocentID==id);
```

html:

```
@model Docent
<h4>My Locations</h4>
@foreach (var item in Model.Locaties)
{
  @item.Name @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteLocaties", new { id = item.LocatieID })
}

<h4>My Competences</h4>
@foreach (var item in Model.Competenties)
{
  @item.Name @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteCompetenties", new { id = item.CompetentiesID })
}
```